# getter setter c++ not as expected

Tags: c++, c++11, getter-setter

i want to ask about getters/setters. i have 2 classes besides 'main'. I get an error when accessing a variable from a different class.

this is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Employee {
  private:
    // Private attribute
    int salary;

  public:
    // Setter
    void setSalary(int s) {
      salary = s;
    }
    // Getter
    int getSalary() {
      return salary;
    }
};

class boss {
  public: 
  void tes() {
    Employee myObj;
    cout << "(2) boss ask salary:  " << myObj.getSalary() << "?\n";

    myObj.setSalary(60000);
    cout << "(3) boss said new salary:  " << myObj.getSalary() << "\n";
  }
};

int main() {
  Employee myObj;
  myObj.setSalary(50000);
  cout << "(1) main said salary: " << myObj.getSalary() << "\n";

  boss bs;
  bs.tes();

  return 0;
}
```

and output:

```
(1) main said salary: 50000
(2) boss ask salary:  32649?
(3) boss said new salary:  60000
```

why is the result in line 2 not as expected? should be 50000. How do I write the code to make it correct?
thank you.

Comment: Try printing the address of each `Employee`. What do the results tell you?

Comment: You've created 2 entirely different objects of type `Employee`: one in `main` and one in `boss::tes`. Since the salary of the one in `tes` is not initialized before it's read, `getSalary()` could return arbitrary values. You probably should pass the existing `Employee` object to `tes` by reference instead... `void tes(Employee& myObj) { cout << ...`; Btw: `getSalary` should be `const`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In main function you have one instance of Employee to which you set a salary of 50000.
In `boss.tes()` function, you have a different instance of `Employee`, which doesn't have any value in salary member, that is the reason you get a "garbage" value when printing 'boss ask salary'.

I don't know what should be the logic in your code, but in case you want it to be the same salary, you need to change the `tes()` method to receive `Employee&` and then it will work for you.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Employee {
  private:
    // Private attribute
    int salary;

  public:
    // Setter
    void setSalary(int s) {
      salary = s;
    }
    // Getter
    int getSalary() {
      return salary;
    }
};

class boss {
  public: 
  void tes(Employee& employee) {
    cout << "(2) boss ask salary:  " << employee.getSalary() << "?\n";

    employee.setSalary(60000);
    cout << "(3) boss said new salary:  " << employee.getSalary() << "\n";
  }
};

int main() {
  Employee myObj;
  myObj.setSalary(50000);
  cout << "(1) main said salary: " << myObj.getSalary() << "\n";

  boss bs;
  bs.tes(myObj);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you. That was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A function is a world on its own. This means that if you call a function it will have only the variables you have declared inside and the ones you passed. To use the object you declared in main inside the other object's method you will have to pass it inside the call.

Your main would be:

```
int main() {
  Employee myObj;
  myObj.setSalary(50000);
  cout << "(1) main said salary: " << myObj.getSalary() << "\n";

  boss bs;
  bs.tes(myObj);

  return 0;
}
```

And your Boss class would be:

```
class boss {
  public: 
  void tes(Employee myObj) {
    cout << "(2) boss ask salary:  " << myObj.getSalary() << "?\n";

    myObj.setSalary(60000);
    cout << "(3) boss said new salary:  " << myObj.getSalary() << "\n";
  }
};
```

Remember that if you don't pass the address of the object (as i did) the changes you made to it inside the function will no longer exist when it ends

Comment: Thanks you. That was helpful.